# Free shipping Coupon being accepted but shipping amount not deducted

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, free-shipping, ce-1.9.2.1

I have created a free shipping coupon in shopping cart price rule. The free shipping option is set to "For Shipments with Matching Items" in the "Action" tab. There are no conditions as it is applicable to all the Items and the coupon is being accepted but the shipping amount is not being deducted from the subtotal. Does anyone know what is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Without more information, concerning magento version 1 vs 2, CE vs EE it is terribly hard to answer your question. Someone would need to know the exacts of the situation in order to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hello Brian thank you for pointing it out, I have Community Edition version 1.9.2.1. Let me know if you need any further information

Comment: I'm having the same issue on 1.7.0.2 CE - Followed all the video guides but the shipping price doesnt change after applying the coupon code(the code applies, but price stays).

Have you been able to figure out the issue?